# Image to move to center of window on window resize with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, center

so I've been playing with this for about an hour and having be searching through stackoverflow. I am just trying to get this image that I have set to center of the screen to stay in the center based on window resizing. I have found something that kind of does this except for the fact that it may lose track of center of the screen after awhile and get off center. Below is the code I am using.

HTML

```
<img data-target="#csgo1"  class="csgo img" align="middle" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6f/Smiley_Face.png"
<center><img data-target="#csgo1" style="display:none;" id="csgo1" class="csgo1 img" align="middle" src="pictures/csgo.png"></center>
```

CSS

```
.img
{
cursor:pointer;
}
.csgo1
{
opacity:.35;
-webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
margin:0 auto;
border-left: 75px;
border-right: 75px;
border-top:10px;
border-bottom:10px;
border-color:#0a1b0a;
border-style:solid;
left:40%;
top:100px;
position:fixed;
z-index:100;
transition: 1s ease;
}
.csgo1:hover
{
opacity:1;
-webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
-ms-transform: scale(1.05);
transform: scale(1.05);
transition: 1s ease;
}
```

JQuery

```
//function to set image in center of screen
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.img').on('click', function(){
var target = $($(this).data('target'));
if(target.css('display') == "none"){ 
    target.attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
    $(".content").animate({opacity: .1});
    $(".footer").animate({opacity: .1});
    target.attr('style', 'height:' + this.height*2 + 'px;');
    target.attr('style', 'width:' + this.width*2 + 'px;');
target.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - target.outerHeight()) / 2)) + "px");
target.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - target.outerWidth()) / 2)) + "px");
test = true;
    target.fadeIn();
}else{
    target.hide();
    test = false
    $(".content").animate({opacity: 1}, 10);
    $(".footer").animate({opacity: 1}, 10);
 }
});
});


//function to resize image on window resize
$(window).resize(function() {
var curWidth = $(window).width(); //store the window's current width
var curHeight = $(window).height(); 
var delta = (curWidth- origWidth);
var charlie = (curHeight- origHeight);
$(".csgo1").offset({left:($(".csgo1").offset().left + delta)});
$(".csgo1").offset({top:($(".csgo1").offset().top + charlie)});
origWidth = curWidth;
origHeight = curHeight;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nathanahartmann/dqjua4dk/

Any help on how to get a more centered picture while it not losing track of center of the window would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is my actual site I am working on to fix this.
nathanahartmann.com

Using text-align:center;
and top:calc(50%); left:calc(50%);
as listed below has not correctly centered all of my images. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: P.S: the `<center>` tag is long deprecated. Use CSS `text-align: center` instead.

Comment: `text-align: center` will do the trick for you but on horizontal axis. Its vertical centering which takes additional logic. You can [**follow the tutorials here**](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide).

Comment: My entire body is centered with margin: 0 auto; this still yields awkward results with some images still being just off centered enough that this doesn't work and the <center> was just an attempt to fix this. I have since taken it out and forgot to remove it from this example.

Comment: Do you want keep in center (both axis) on scrolling also??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I know this does not answer your question, but just to share a way I'd do it:

```js
var $lb = $("<div/>", {
    id: "lightbox",
    appendTo: "body",
    click :function() {
      $(this).removeClass("show");
    }
  });

$("[data-full]").click(function(){
  $lb.css({backgroundImage:"url('"+$(this).data("full")+"')"}).addClass("show");
});
```

```css
html, body{height:100%;margin:0;}

#lightbox{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 400px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7) none 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
          transition: 0.7s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 90%; height: 90%;
  margin: 5%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}#lightbox.show{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}#lightbox:after{
  content:"×";
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  right: 10px; top: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="//placehold.it/120x120/4af/fff/&text=Click+me"
     data-full="//placehold.it/800x800/4af/fff/&text=Click+me">

<img src="//placehold.it/120x60/a4f/&text=Click+me"
     data-full="//placehold.it/800x400/a4f/&text=Click+me">
```

Comment: I really like this, but the way I was doing it was "a lot of jquery" as others have said, but made it extremely easy to module it with other images, with just an addition of a few pieces, my code worked with any image inserted into the website. This is nice but has a lot of set up for all images and doesn't directly work with pictures well it seems.

Comment: @nathanhartmann this works very well with all kind of images (if you have a relatively good quality for the "large" image.) If the image you're opening inside the lightbox is small than a small piece of JS should be written to keep the image on it's natural size instead of going to `"contain"`.

Comment: @nathanhartmann the code as it's written need 0 setup. You just need to provide an `<img>` tag with the `src=""` set to the thumbnail and the `data-full=""` set to the HQ image path.

Comment: @nathanhartmann here's a similar advanced version https://github.com/rokobuljan/Darkbox-Gallery that handles such cases as you can see in the [javascript](https://github.com/rokobuljan/Darkbox-Gallery/blob/master/darkbox.js) code.

Comment: I see how this works now and it's terrific :) may I use this within my code for my personal website if you don't mind? it's just a resume website.

Comment: @nathanhartmann sure you're welcome to use and improve the code.

Comment: I appreciate Roko :] Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

hi please find below codepen.
but understand that this code will only work if your image height and width is fix.

you don't need that much javascript for that, instead use CSS.

HTML part,

```
<div class="containerDiv">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6f/Smiley_Face.png" />
</div>
```

CSS part,

```
.containerDiv
{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  height:100vh;
}
.containerDiv img
{
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(50% - 90px);
  left:calc(50% - 90px);
}
```

See the [Demo](http://codepen.io/tejpalpathak/pen/Wwpqgo)

Comment: this kind of worked, except some of my images are a bit bigger, and it doesn't seem to be centering them correctly.
https://jsfiddle.net/nathanahartmann/54phnsmc/

Comment: in you fiddle you written something like.
.csgo
{

 width:375px;
 border: 3px ridge #00cc00;
 margin-left:20px;
 height:208px;
}

so is it going to be fix height or width?

Comment: for the picture size? yes